# Is it possible to do geospatial queries in sanity.io?

Tags: sanity, groq

I found out that sanity supports [Geopoint type](https://www.sanity.io/docs/schema-types/geopoint-type), but I could not find any information if it's possible to do any filter operation on this type. Are geospatial queries possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler syntax for geospatial queries is on the roadmap.

If you for instance want to make a Lat/Lng bounded query, you can do that the following way, given the schema:

```
export default {
   name: 'aDocumentType',
   type: 'document',
   fields: [
    {
       name: 'position',
       type: 'geopoint'
    }
   ]
}
```

Let's say we have used Mapbox, and have a [LngLatBounds](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#lnglatbounds) object. Now we can make a query, using the [params](https://www.sanity.io/docs/client-libraries/js-client#performing-queries) that maps to this object:

```
*[
  _type == "aDocumentType &&
  position.lng < $bounds._ne.lng &&
  position.lat < $bounds._ne.lat &&
  position.lng > $bounds._sw.lng &&
  position.lat > $bounds._sw.lat &&
]
```